# Do integrated condenser tumble dryers exist?

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-counters

We're looking to fit a condenser tumble dryer into a kitchen unit.

It is possible to buy both integrated and free-standing vented dryers, but only a free-standing condenser. Searching the internet we have not been able to find an integrated condenser dryer, i.e. one that can be built into a unit.

We have tried Bosch, AEG, Miele, etc.

Does anyone know why? Or know of a good integrated vented dryer?

We can't be the first to want to put a condenser dryer in a unit.

Comment: Go for freestanding but stackable.

Comment: Some condenser dryers (e.g. mine) will eventually clog up and stop condensing. It will still dry, but all the humidity escapes into the room. This has happened twice in 5 years. I'm guessing that would be bad if the unit was integrated.  To fix it I needed access to the back of the unit.

Comment: I wasn't aware they made integrated dryers at all. Like thebjorn mentions, this seems like a bad idea in general. These are appliances that need regular maintenance and having access to all parts would seem important.